# Equivalent to WebApplicationException(String message, int status) in JavaEE6

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I know that the method is introduced in Java EE 7 with JAX-RS 2.0.

I want to throw such exception with detailMessage included in Java EE 6.

In Java EE 7 I could simply do:

```
throw new WebApplicationException("My Error Msg", statusCode);
```

But how can I do this with Java EE 6?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html